# Which pattern or structure

Tags: database, design-patterns, interface, field, structure

I have a database table that holds various types of the same entity.
Suppose I have a table named `dbo.PERSONEL` which holds data for `Engineer`, `Constructor`, `Manager`, `Secretary` etc.)

But each specific personel type uses only some and different properties of the table.
`Engineer` uses `[ENGINEERING_TYPE]` and `[IS_OFF_FIELD]` fields while `Secretary` uses `[OFFICE_ID]` and `[DOES_USE_COMPUTER]` fields but not the fields that `Engineer` uses).

How should I design my interfaces, classes etc. Is there an appropriate design pattern for **[CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)** operations on such a table structure?

Answer (score 0):

Java-wise this sounds strait forward to me: simply create a parent class `Personel.java` that holds all generic properties, e.g. `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` etc. Create a sub-class for each individual personel types, e.g. `Engineer.java`, `Manager.java` that extend `Personal.java` and hold type specific properties, e.g. `engineeringType`.

The problem becomes more interesting when mapping those Java classes to your DB and the solution depends on your DB-access framework (if you are going to use one). [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) and [Mybatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/) would work fine for your scenario with the proposed table and Java structure.

Comment: That's what comes into mind first. But how to implement tha SCRUD operations based on Design Patterns?

Comment: If you mean CRUD operations as in Create, Read, Update and Delete this is beyond the scope of a single clear cut design pattern. Your db-access framework might take care of it out-of-the-box, e.g. Hibernate would map your entity bean modifications automatically to the database.

Comment: I am not currently using any Frameworks in the project. Just plain old ADO.NET. Ao I am free to apply and patterns to maintain flexibility, mintability and code effectiveness.